# Hyperbola and Asymptote

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

The chord $QQ'$ of a hyperbola $\frac{x^2}{a^2} -\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$  is parallel to the tangent at $P$. The segments $PN$, $QM$ and $Q'M'$ are perpendiculars to an asymptote. Show that $QM \cdot Q'M' = PN^2$.

I did the following step .

Coordinates of $P,Q$ and $Q'$ are $(x_1,y_1)$ , $(x_2,y_2)$ and $(x_3,y_3)$

The asymptote equation is $\frac{x}{a} -\frac{y}{b} =0$

Using distance of Perpendicular line formula

Let  $$PN = \frac{\frac{x_1}{a} -\frac{y_1}{b}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}}}\\
QM= \frac{\frac{x_2}{a} -\frac{y_2}{b}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}}}\\
Q'M'= \frac{\frac{\ x_3}{a} -\frac{\ y_3}{b}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}}}$$

Slope at $P$ is $\frac{b^2 x_1}{a^2 y_1}$

Slope of $QQ'$ is $\frac{y_2 - y_3}{x_2 - x_3}$

$\frac{b^2 x_1}{a^2 y_1}$=$\frac{y_2 - y_3}{x_2 - x_3}$

As $QQ'$ is parallel to Tangent at $P$ hence both slopes are equal , using above relation.

At the end I tried to compare $PN^2 = QM\cdot Q'M'$ using the "slope of $QQ'$ equals the slope of $P$" condition but getting struck.

Comment: I tried this problem and jolted all the steps, i am not able to arrive at the concluding answer

Comment: I edited your formulas. Could you please check that they are correct and correct the ones that are wrong (especially the slope at $P$; I couldn't tell what that was supposed to be).

Comment: @Arthur Thanks you for editing

Comment: @Arthur Slope at P is correct, 2x1/a^2 - 2y1y'/b^2 =0 which yields (y'=b^2 x1/a^2y1)

Comment: OK, so it's supposed to be a product. Cool. Also, go easy on the "`\ `", as the math engine usually fixes spacing between symbols on its own pretty well.

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi Did you try eliminating $y_i$ using $\frac{x_i^2}{a^2}-\frac{y_i^2}{b^2}=1$?

Comment: It may be easier to work with parametrization by hyperbolic functions $x=a \cosh(t)$, $y=b \sinh(t)$.

Comment: @Math Lover Yes i tried to eliminate but not able to achieve the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will present two solutions (A) and (B). I have found solution (B) 2 months after I wrote solution (A). By far, solution (B), is the simplest one.

**Solution (A)**

See figure 1 below.

Hyperbola $(H)$ with equation

$$\tag{A0} \dfrac{x^2}{a^2}-\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

can be described using the classical parametrization :

$$\tag{A1} x=a \cosh(t), \ \ y=b \sinh(t).$$

Let $t,t',t''$ be the parameters corresponding to points $Q,Q',P$ resp. Let:

$$\tag{A2} d=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{a^2}+\dfrac{1}{b^2}}}.$$

The distance of point $Q$ with coordinates (A1) to the asymptote of $(H)$ (depicted in green on the figure) with equation $\frac{x}{a}-\tfrac{y}{b}=0$ is (you have done this computation):

$$\tag{A3} QM=d(\cosh(t)-\sinh(t))=d e^{-t} \ \text{; thus} \ Q'M'=d e^{-t'} \ \text{and} \  PN=d e^{-t''}.$$

(see for example http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html). Thus, what we need to prove becomes

$$d e^{-t}d e^{-t'}=(d e^{-t''})^2.$$

Said otherwise, we have to establish the (pretty) result that

$$\tag{A4}t''=\tfrac12 (t+t').$$

Let us work backwards : we are going to prove that the tangent to $(H)$ at point $P'$ of the hyperbola with parameter $\tfrac12 (t+t')$  is parallel to line segment $QQ'$. (both in blue on the picture).

This is rather easy.

- on the one hand, the tangent in $P'$ to $(H)$ has equation (see explanation below):

$$\tag{A5}x \dfrac{1}{a} \cosh(\tfrac12 (t+t'))- y.\dfrac{1}{b} \sinh(\tfrac12 (t+t'))=1.$$

A directing vector of this tangent is thus

$$\vec{V}=\binom{\tfrac{1}{b} \sinh(\tfrac12 (t+t'))}{\tfrac{1}{a} \cosh(\tfrac12 (t+t'))}=\tfrac{1}{ab}\binom{a \sinh(\tfrac12 (t+t'))}{b \cosh(\tfrac12 (t+t'))}.$$

(I use here the fact that a straight line with equation $ux+vy+w=0$ has $\binom{v}{-u}$ as a directing vector).

- on the other hand, vector $\vec{QQ'}=\binom{a(\cosh(t')-\cosh(t))}{b(\sinh(t')-\sinh(t))}=\binom{2a\sinh(\tfrac12 (t+t'))\sinh(\tfrac12 (t-t'))}{2b\cosh(\tfrac12 (t+t'))\sinh(\tfrac12 (t-t'))},$

$$\vec{QQ'}=2\sinh(\tfrac12 (t-t'))\binom{a\sinh(\tfrac12 (t+t'))}{b\cosh(\tfrac12 (t+t'))}.$$

Parallelism is a consequence of the fact that vectors $\vec{V}$ and $\vec{QQ'}$ are proportional.

Explanation for (A5) : the generic formula for the tangent to $(H)$ in $(x_0,y_0)$ is, using (A0) :

$$\dfrac{x x_0}{a^2}-\dfrac{y y_0}{b^2}=1.$$

**Important remark:** We have the interesting result $MN=NM'$. It can be easily proved using the concept of *conjugate diameters*.

[image]

**Solution (B)**

(see figure 2 below).

Let us take the following axes. Let the asymptote of hyperbola (H) on which the projection is done be the $y$ (ordinate) axis, and axes' intersection point as the origin. Thus, the other asymptote has equation $y=ax$ for a certain $a \in \mathbb{R}$, giving the following equation for (H):

$$\tag{B1}y=ax+\dfrac{b}{x} \ \ \ \text{with} \ \ \ a \in \mathbb{R}, b \in  \mathbb{R^*}$$

In order to simplify our explanation, let us consider the case of equation

$$\tag{B2}h(x)=y=x-\dfrac{1}{x}$$

(The general case (B1) is an immediate generalization of (B2)).

Let $Q_k(x_k,y_k:=h(x_k)) \ \  (k=1,2)$ two points on the hyperbola with equation (B2) situated on the same branch of (H). We can assume WLOG, by the fact that $h$ is an odd function, that $x_1>0$ and $x_2>0$ .

The slope of line segment $Q_1Q_2$ is:

$$\tag{B3}s=\dfrac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=\dfrac{\left(x_2-\dfrac{1}{x_2}\right)-\left(x_1-\dfrac{1}{x_1}\right)}{x_2-x_1}=1+\dfrac{1}{x_1x_2}.$$

Let $M_k$ be the projection of $Q_k$ on the $y$ axis. As distance $Q_kM_k$ is equal to $x_k$, the issue is to show that, at point $P$ with abscissa $x_3:=\sqrt{x_1x_2}$, the tangent has a slope equal to $s$ as given in (B3).

In fact, differentiation of (B2) gives the following expression for the slope of the tangent in $x$:

$$\tag{B4}h'(x)=1+\dfrac{1}{x^2}$$
Computed for $x=x_3$, we find back at once (B3).

[image]

Remark: The slope of the tangent could have been directly obtained by taking the limit of expression (B3) when $x_1 \to x$ and $x_2 \to x$.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, In case of Line Equation even on application of Correct Concept, individual get struck, you have seen that my approach was correct but could not prove the answer

Comment: Yes. Do you agree with my computations ?

Comment: Yes , I have so many question on Line Equation but decided bot to post it .Today i will do it

Comment: Thanks for your effort in solving this problem . If any problem in geometry occurs i will direct it to you but only and only if I am struck at certain steps

Comment: I see you are very perseverant. May I ask you what is your country ?

Comment: I am from India

Comment: I have found a solution which is very simple compared to the first one. I have written it down as "Solution B".